When i pass table.arn which is of type Output[str] to resources property of GetPolicyDocumentStatementArgs which is of type str it still works
What's going on here. arn property of Table (Dynamo) is of type Output[str] but when I just pass it to place which expect string e.g. resources property of GetPolicyDocumentStatementArgs it still works and everything gets created properly. No errors except IDE warning.  Does Pulumi automatically run apply or what's going on?
# Create a DynamoDB table
    dynamo_table = aws.dynamodb.Table(
        "exampleTable",
        attributes=[aws.dynamodb.TableAttributeArgs(name="Id", type="S")],
        hash_key="Id",
        billing_mode="PAY_PER_REQUEST",
    )

    # Define the policy document to allow access to the DynamoDB table
    policy_document = aws.iam.get_policy_document(
        statements=[
            aws.iam.GetPolicyDocumentStatementArgs(
                effect="Allow",
                actions=[
                    "dynamodb:Query",
                    "dynamodb:Scan",
                    "dynamodb:GetItem",
                    "dynamodb:PutItem",
                    "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                    "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                ],
                resources=[dynamo_table.arn],
            )
        ]
    )

    # Create an IAM role with the DynamoDB access policy
    role = aws.iam.Role(
        "dynamoAccessRole",
        assume_role_policy=aws.iam.get_policy_document(
            statements=[
                aws.iam.GetPolicyDocumentStatementArgs(
                    effect="Allow",
                    actions=["sts:AssumeRole"],
                    principals=[
                        aws.iam.GetPolicyDocumentStatementPrincipalArgs(
                            type="Service", identifiers=["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
                        )
                    ],
                )
            ]
        ).json,
    )```

